# Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I encounter the following error:

```
Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys, or yourself.
```

when I was trying these commands

```
USE ASPState
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON CreateTempTables TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON DeleteExpiredSessions TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON GetMajorVersion TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON GetHashCode TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempGetAppID TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempGetStateItem TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempGetStateItem2 TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempGetStateItem3 TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempGetStateItemExclusive TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempGetStateItemExclusive2 TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempGetStateItemExclusive3 TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempGetVersion TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempInsertStateItemLong TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempInsertStateItemShort TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempInsertUninitializedItem TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempReleaseStateItemExclusive TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempRemoveStateItem TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempResetTimeout TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempUpdateStateItemLong TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempUpdateStateItemLongNullShort TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempUpdateStateItemShort TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON TempUpdateStateItemShortNullLong TO [R2Server\AAOUser]
GO
```

So, how do I know what type of permissions my account `R2Server\AAOUser` have for the database `ASPState`? and what are the ways to solve the error (so that I can grant these permissions to my account)?

Comment: Is your user sysadmin on the server? Or db owner on that db?

Comment: Actually none. (my user account is not a `sysadmin` nor `db owner`.)

Comment: I think I find out that I am the `db owner` using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. So, I can conclude that I do not need to grant myself any permission since I am the owner of the `ASPState` database. right?

Comment: You're right. If you're the db owner you don't need any other database permissions.

Comment: @Thanks Marian, probably you would like to put your answer and include what commands to be type into sqlcmd so that one know what permissions he has on the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the comments, if you're already the db owner of that database, than you don't need to grant any permission for the db.

Now, in order to find out what specific permissions you have, you can use the following queries:

- find permissions on specific db:

  ```
  USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
  SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE');
  GO
  ```
- find permissions on all the server:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER');
  GO
  ```

See some other info here: [Find out SQL Server Logins and associated Server Roles](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sa/transactsql/thread/84ddd8e2-e8eb-4b36-beba-5ae51ca46c8c), on MSDN forum.

Comment: For those that don't know much about SQL, you have to replace `AdventureWorks2008R2` with your own database name. The `fn_my_permissions` part is the same for all databases.